# Calculating frequencies from .mp3 or .wav files?

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, fft, pitch-tracking

I'm trying to do some note recognition on `mp3` or `wav` files.

The problem is: How do I use the FFT on the files?

I prefer Java solutions,  but I'm up for suggestions.

Comment: -1 Why would this badly worded question with no attempt at finding a solution get up-voted? He didn't even look at the myriad of SO clones, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287518/reliable-and-fast-fft-in-java

Comment: I tried finding a solution. Been looking for a week and had no luck.

Comment: Notice the link that's just one of many such pages in the "related" list on the right.

Comment: Doesn't really answer what I'm looking for...

Comment: Hence my comment about not putting any effort into it. What do you have? What do you need added? What have you tried? How has it failed?

Comment: I have FFT Libraries to use. I have no idea how to set it up. Sorry that that question wasn't worded perfectly but I'm having trouble to setting it up so I can use FFT. I want to get the data from the audio file.

Comment: Guess this is going to be the only time I'm here. I'll just figure this out myself.

Comment: @Daniel: I have personally answered several questions similar to this on SO already and I know others have too - if you just spend a few minutes reading some these previous questions and answers on the subject you should have all the information you need.

Comment: Ok... so blast me because I asked. Thanks... next... anymore people that would like to add -1. Go straight ahead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spectrum Analysis using Java, Sampling Frequency, Folding Frequency, and the FFT Algorithm http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3380031

Comment: Thanks... I'll look into this. I've gotten to a point where I can use Micheal T Flanagan's Java library for Fourier Transform. Hopefully this will give me a better understanding of what I need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Some example links are:

- [Here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708613/graphing-the-pitch-frequency-of-a-sound)
- [An FFT java implementation at Princeton.](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/FFT.java.html)