# how to detect the pitch of recorded sound sample

Tags: android, audio-streaming, audio-recording, pitch-tracking

I'd like to analyze a piece of a recorded sound sample and find it's properties like pitch and so.
I have tried to analyze the recorded bytes of the buffer with no success.
How it can be done?

Comment: See _Understanding Digital Signal Processing_, by Richard G. Lyons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to look into [FFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform).

Then do something like this pseudocode indicates :

```
Complex in[1024];
Complex out[1024];
Copy your signal into in
FFT(in, out)
for every member of out compute sqrt(a^2+b^2)
To find frequency with highest power scan for the maximum value in the first 512 points in out
```

Check also out the original post of the buddy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708613/graphing-the-pitch-frequency-of-a-sound) because it is probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Use fast Fourier transform.. Libraries available for most languages. Bytes are no good, can be mp3 encoded or wav/pcm.. You need to decide then analyze.

DG